# Mongodb - aggregate items from array, matching item property or subarray item property

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents with the following structure:

```
{
  _id: "UNIQUE_ID",
  myarray: [
    {
      mykey: '12345',
      // other fields
    },
    {
      // other fields
      nestedarray: [
        {
          mykey: '67890',
          // other fields
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I need to return all items from `myarray` on which `mykey` (on items of `myarray` or `nestedarray`) belongs to a set of values. For example, for the document above, if the set of values is `['12345, '67890']`, both items from `myarray` should be returned.

I'm using the following code to do that:

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": documentId,
      $or: [
        { "myarray": {$elemMatch: {"mykey": { $in: ['12345, '67890'] } } } },
        { "myarray.$.nestedarray": {$elemMatch: {"mykey": { $in: ['12345, '67890'] } }} }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      myarray: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$myarray',
          as: 'arrayitem',
          cond: {
            $or: [
              { $eq: ["$$arrayitem.mykey", '12345'] },
              { $eq: ["$$arrayitem.nestedarray.[$].mykey", '12345'] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

But this only return the items on which `mykey` matches at `myarray` level (not matching it inside `nestedarray`).

What am I doing wrong?

Also, how may I use set `['12345, '67890']` instead of single value `'12345'` inside of $filter function?

**Clarifying:**

- If `mykey` match is on an item from `myarray`: include this item (this item will not have a `nestedarray` field)
- If `mykey` match is on an item from `nestedarray`: include the item from `myarray` which contains `nestedarray` (also with full contents of `nestedarray`). This item from `myarray` will not have a `mykey` field

**Example:**

Data:

```
{
  _id: "UNIQUE_ID",
  myarray: [
    {
      mykey: '11111',
      // other fields
    },
    {
      // other fields
      nestedarray: [
        {
          mykey: '22222',
          // other fields
        },
        {
          mykey: '84325',
          // other fields
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      mykey: '645644',
      // other fields
    },
    {
      // other fields
      nestedarray: [
        {
          mykey: '23242',
          // other fields
        },
        {
          mykey: '23433',
          // other fields
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Set of values: `['11111', '22222']`

Expected query result:

```
{
  _id: "UNIQUE_ID",
  myarray: [
    {
      mykey: '11111',
      // other fields
    },
    {
      // other fields
      nestedarray: [
        {
          mykey: '22222',
          // other fields
        },
        {
          mykey: '84325',
          // other fields
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What if `mykey` exists in `nestedarray` but not in `myArray`?

Comment: Then the item from `myarray` which contains `nestedarray` should be included, and only the matching item(s) from `nestedarray` should be included

Comment: ok then the below **answers** will work for you.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet actually all items from `nestedarray` will be required (even if only one of them matches).

Comment: So basically you don't want to filter the `nestedarray` array?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I've edited my question to make it clearer. Please let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Still unclear what are asking. Could you explain with some sample data and the output. Nd also you van follow mickl's answer as well

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet added an example. Will also check mickl's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) and then as `cond` you can either directly check `mykey` or use [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) for an array.

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            myarray: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$myarray",
                    cond: {
                        $or: [
                            { $in: [ "$$this.mykey", ["11111", "22222"] ] },
                            { $anyElementTrue: [ 
                                { 
                                    $map: { 
                                        input: { $ifNull: [ "$$this.nestedarray", [] ] }, 
                                        as: "na", 
                                        in: { $in: [ "$$na.mykey", ["11111", "22222"] ] } 
                                    } 
                                } 
                                ] 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j1YtZz9S4XS)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Tried it, but this only returned the item with the non-nested `mykey`.

Comment: @GCSDC that was a bit unclear to me, modified (and simplified) my answer, works fine with your example

Comment: Thats what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": documentId }},
  { "$project": {
    "myarray": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$myarray",
            "as": "arrayitem",
            "in": {
              "mykey": "$$arrayitem.mykey",
              "nestedarray": "$$arrayitem.nestedarray",
              "aaaa": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$$arrayitem.nestedarray",
                  "as": "vv",
                  "cond": { "$in": ["$$vv.mykey", ["12345", "67890"]] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "as": "ff",
        "cond": {
          "$or": [
            { "$in": ["$$ff.mykey", ["12345", "67890"]] },
            { "$gte": [{ "$size": { "$ifNull": ["$$ff.aaaa", []] }}, 1] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { "myarray.aaaa": 0 }}
])
```

Here is the working [**`example`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XXDPCM-D5HH)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In this case, should I keep `$match` exactly as I posted on my question, or should I drop it (in this case, how to match document _id)?

Comment: Use the single `$match` with `_id`. Rest of the thing `$filter` will do.

Comment: Tried it, but I'm getting the following error `errmsg:"The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null"`

Comment: Updated my answer again

Comment: Almost it. The only issue is that it is not bringing the other properties for `myarray` items (only `mykey` or `nestedarray`). I'm trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Add the other properties where I have added `"mykey": "$$arrayitem.mykey". Now for the other fields do this `"otherField": "$$arrayitem.otherField",`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191566/discussion-between-gcsdc-and-anthony-winzlet).